# What is the difference between autowire = "no" and autowire = "default"?

Tags: spring, autowired

What is the difference between autowire = "no" and autowire = "default"? And if they're the same, then why do we have these 2 options.

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164330/what-is-the-meaning-and-what-it-does-autowire-default-in-spring-in-application. they are same

Comment: @MarounMaroun then why two diff. modes ?
And the documentation says :

"no" The traditional Spring default. No automagical wiring. Bean references 
 must be defined in the XML file via the <ref/> element (or "ref" attribute). We recommend this in most cases as it 
 makes documentation more explicit. Note that this default mode also allows for annotation-driven autowiring, if 
 activated. "no" refers to externally driven autowiring only, not affecting any autowiring demands that the bean 
 class itself expresses.

Default mode allow for annotation driven programming  - Meaning?

Comment: @parul I change my answer, now it's better.

Comment: @MarounMaroun   they are differents

Comment: @JekinKalariya  they are differents

Answer (score 1):

> Beans
>
> The default is "default", indicating inheritance from outer 'beans'
>   sections in case of nesting, otherwise falling back to "no" (i.e. no
>   externally driven autowiring).
>
> Bean
>
> It can be shared through the 'default-autowire' attribute at the
>   'beans' level and potentially inherited from outer 'beans' defaults in
>   case of nested 'beans' sections (e.g. with different profiles).

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd

In the tag `<beans>` you can set which will be the default autowire (default-autowire) for this group of beans. If you don't define it, the value it will use will be no.

But if you use a value different from "default" or "no" in your `<beans>` tag, then this value will be used in your beans.

```
<beans default-autowire="ByName">
<bean autowire="default">
```

In the example above the default in your bean will be "ByName".

You can see more about autowire here: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-beans-auto-wiring-example-using-xml-configuration/